# Unity PlayerPrefs saving

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use some `PlayerPrefs` in my Unity app (platforms are: iOS, Android, Windows). Now I want to release update, so it's a question: when users update there apps - will `PlayerPrefs` be saved? The problem is that I store the game progress in this prefs and if users will lose it after update - it will be very bad.

Is there reliable information about this question?

Answer (score 5):

How will you release this update? A new version of the application, or new content streamed in through asset bundles?

If it's a new version of the application, but it's installed as an update and overwrites the old version, then playerprefs will remain unchanged. If it's installed seperately however, the saved data will be lost.

If you're using asset bundles, no worries, nothing will break. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Player prefs persist if you just update the app.